# tkinter frame resizes when adding widget and why always my label is in centre position?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import os
import sys
import datetime

connection = sqlite3.connect("employees.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        #<-----Defining Frames----->
        main_frame = Frame(self.master)
        main_frame.pack()

        top_frame = Frame(main_frame, width = 1250, height = 50, bg = '#f8f8f8', padx = 20, relief = SUNKEN, borderwidth = 1)
        top_frame.pack(side = TOP, fill = X)

        top_right_frame = Frame(top_frame, width = 100, height = 20, bg = '#f8f8f8', relief = SUNKEN, borderwidth = 0)
        top_right_frame.pack(side = RIGHT)

        center_frame = Frame(main_frame, width = 1350, height = 690, relief = RIDGE, bg = '#e6e6ff', borderwidth = 1)
        center_frame.pack(side = TOP)

        left_center_frame = Frame(center_frame, width = 250, height = 690, relief = SUNKEN, bg = '#e6e6ff', borderwidth = 1)
        left_center_frame.pack(side = LEFT)

        right_center_frame = Frame(center_frame, width = 1100, height = 690, relief = SUNKEN, bg = '#e6e6ff', borderwidth = 1)
        right_center_frame.pack(side = LEFT)

        bottom_frame = Frame(main_frame, width = 1350, height = 10, relief = SUNKEN, bg = '#8080ff', borderwidth = 0)
        bottom_frame.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = X)

        label_swap_type = Frame(left_center_frame, width = 250, height = 50, relief = RIDGE, bg = '#e6e6ff', borderwidth = 1)
        label_swap_type.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

        #<-----Defining Labels----->
        label_main_title = Label(top_frame, text = "Advisor Roster Swap", bg = '#f8f8f8', font = ("TIMES",20), justify = CENTER)
        label_main_title.pack()

        label_current_day = Label(top_right_frame, text = timeDetails().current_date(), bg = '#f8f8f8', font = ("Times New Roman",10), anchor = NE)
        label_current_day.pack(side = RIGHT)

        label_bottom_frame = Label(bottom_frame, text = "© Vodafone WFM | RTA", font = ("Times New Roman",10), justify = CENTER, fg= '#ffffff', bg = '#8080ff' )
        label_bottom_frame.pack(side = BOTTOM)

        #swap_type = ['One way swap', 'Two way swap']
        #swap_type_combobox = ttk.Combobox(left_center_frame, value = swap_type)
        #swap_type_combobox.current(0)
        #swap_type_combobox.grid(row = 0, column = 1)


class timeDetails():
    def current_date(self):
        now =  datetime.datetime.now()
        return now.strftime("%A, %B %d")


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    root.title("Advisor Roster Swap")
    root.geometry("1350x750+35`enter code here`0+200")
    root.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

tkinter frame resizes when adding widget and why is my label always is in the center position? This makes my window look ugly. Can someone please look into this? I have checked using Labelframe, frames etc. gave options like side = TOP; however, it shows in the middle of the left_center_frame

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and don't know where to paste the picture...
When you run this code, you will see "swap_type_frame" which is a labelFrame appears in center position of the left_center_frame. I want this to be on the top...

Comment: Try `left_center_frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)`.

Comment: voila!!!!! that seems to be worked....
thanks so much man